# Can Some Explain use of (%*[\n] %[^\n]) During String Input

Tags: c, string, scanf

30 Day code challenge Question 2 Day 1 Hacker Rank Question.

Can Some Explain use of `(%*[\n] %[^\n])` During String Input?

Comment: what did the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) tell you?

Comment: In a single format string, the first term is a long-winded way of doing what the single space does far more succinctly.  It skips newlines, and the space skips white space (blanks, tabs, newlines).

Answer (score 3):

1. `%*[\n]` says "accept one or more newlines but do not store them"
2. The space between `]` and `%` says "ignore all the following white spaces"
3. `%[^\n]` says "accept and store any string up to but not including a newline"

Example:

**Character input**

```
              '\n' ' ' ' ' '\t' '\n' '\n' 'a' 'b' 'c' '\n'
              \--/ \--------------------/ \---------/
               |              |                |
Accepted by:   1.             2.               3.
```

So the stored input will be "abc" and `scanf`will return 1 to tell that it matched 1 element.

Notice that input **not** starting with a newline will result in zero matched elements.